# how to save results of perf sched latency? It waits for keyboard input even when redirected to a file

Tags: linux, command, perf

I use the following commands:

```
perf sched record -- sleep 1
perf sched latency
```

It will print the latencies of tasks.

Then, I use command `perf sched latency &> abc.txt`. However, it won't finish, just stuck. The command finish only after I press the key q in my keyboard, which is not suitable for being executed in a bash script.

So how to save the results of the command?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some methods and have a solution.

Using `expect` or `pexpect` I can send q to the process and make it finish, although I need to write another script.

Comment: Can you `echo q | perf sched latency`?  Or maybe just `perf sched latency < /dev/null`?  (While also redirecting its output).  Or even `<&-` to close its stdin, so its read system call will return an error.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, (1) I have tried `echo q | perf sched latency`, it returns "incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)" and has no any other outputs; (2) `perf sched latency < /dev/null` makes no sense and still needs pressing q; (3) `<&-` returns "Missing filename ("less --help" for help)" and has no any other outputs.

Comment: Oh, it's piping into `less`?  Maybe `PAGER=cat  perf sched latency` would work, then.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have try `PAGER=cat  perf sched latency`, which needs pressing q.